# How can we do the log Rotation with compression in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using RotatingFileHandler of python 2.7 and I want to do compression when log size file is increased at a certain limit. So is there any method in python logger to do compression also. Or I have to use another module zipfile or others available.

Comment: This looks pretty useful: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#cookbook-rotator-namer

Comment: Is this method works in python 2.7?

Comment: Their is a doRollover method on the logger that you can probably override.

Comment: @jdowner : Why then logging.Logger.doRollover raises an AttributeError?

Comment: @Dalen because doRollover is a function on the RotatingFileHandler class.

Comment: it means I have to override the doRollover function and implements the compression

Comment: Yes, but you can still use the original method to roll the file, then you gzip it. or go to the site-packages/logging/handlers.py, copy-paste the code of RotatingFileHandler.doRollover() into your class and add the gzipping functionality.

Comment: What the doRollover() does is to close the current log file, rename it and open a fresh one with the old name. You instead have to close the current one, gzip/zip it with appropriate naming in mind, remove the old uncompressed log file, and open a fresh log file with the old name.